# show last post from each category

Tags: laravel

I have two models Post and Category

// migration post

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

// migration category

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

How can I display only the last post from each category in home page?

Comment: Try: `$catList = Category::lists('id');  $post = Post::wherein('category_id', $catList)->groupby('category_id')->latest()->get();`

Comment: @HirenGohel thanks ,but I have this error   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()

Comment: You can use method pluck. Method lists' is removed in Laravel 5.3. Try: `$catList = Category::pluck('id'); $post = Post::wherein('category_id', $catList)->groupby('category_id')->latest()->get();`

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'ex.posts.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `posts` where `category_id` in (1, 2) group by `category_id` order by `created_at` desc)

Comment: Try: `$catList = Category::pluck('id')->all();`

Comment: I have same error

Answer (score 3):

Hiren was close, but you need to go from the category since your `post` is owned by the `category`

```
$category->posts()->latest()->first();
```

Alternatively you could work backwards:

```
$post = Post::latest()->whereHas('category', function($q) use($category_id) {
    return $q->where('id', $category_id);
})->first();
```

For this to work you'll need to define your model relationships:

Category Model needs this function:

```
public function posts() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\Post::class);
}
```

Post Model needs this function:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Category::class);
}
```

To respond to Alexey Mezenin, we can just pass a callback to `with()` to define which posts we want to pull in for each category, performing the correct `eager load`.

```
Category::with(['posts' => function($q) {
    return $q->latest()->first();
})->get();
```

Comment: @user5565240 added additional info about model relationship definitions.

Comment: Just want to say that this solution will take post only for one category and if you'll use it in a loop, it will create [N+1 queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) (101 query for 100 categories).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy you've added another solution (the `with()` one), but it doesn't work, because it will load only one post total and not one post per each category.

Answer (score 1):

An Eloquent solution for loading categories with latest post is to create an additional [`hasOne()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relationship in the `Category` model:

```
public function latestPost()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Post::class)->latest();
}
```

And then use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
Category::with('latestPost')->get();
```

This will generate just 2 queries to DB.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category.category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`category_id` in (1, 2) order by `created_at` desc)

Comment: @user5565240 you can't get this error with my code, you've modified it. Please double check it.

Comment: it gives me empty rows in my table in home page and if I add a category without associated post gives me error

Comment: This was so useful!! Thank you very much Alexey! It totally fixed my scope problem! I was trying to be cool and apply the scope thing I just learned haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->unsignedInteger('author_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('subject');
        $table->text('short');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->integer('view')->default(0);
        $table->integer('status')->default(0);
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('author_id')
              ->references('id')->on('users')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
        // $table->foreign('category_id')
        //       ->references('id')->on('categories')
        //       ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
    // Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

in contoller:

```
    $latestpostlist = News::whereIn('created_at',function($query){
            $query->select(DB::raw('max(created_at)'))
                      ->from('news')
                      ->groupBy('category_id');
    })->get();
```

in your case news will be post. this query worked for me