# How to add relations to notifications? And get the related data in json

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to create relations, and when notifications are fetched via `$user->unreadNotifications` I want to control which fields are shown, and fetch the relations. I cannot figure out where to do this.

I did the following:

1. `php artisan notifications:table`
2. `php artisan make:migration add_relations_to_notifications_table`
3. In this new migration I added `requester_id`.

   ```
   $table->integer('requester_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
   $table->foreign('requester_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
   ```
4. `php migrate`
5. `php artisan make:notification AnInviteWasRequested`

Then in `AnInviteWasRequested` I removed the `toArray` and replaced it with `toDatabase`:

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'requester_id' => Auth::guard('api')->user()->id
    ];
}
```

However this does not set the `requester_id` field, it just put json into the `data` column that looks like this: `{"requester_id":1}`.

Is there anyway to get this to update the `requester_id` field instead of updating `data`?

And also is it possible somewhere, like a Model file (not in `vendor` dir) to control which fields are displayed when `$user->unreadNotifications` is done?

Comment: should not be any problem if you change migration

Comment: Yea. You shouldn't do any changes on any files inside `vendor` directory. I suggest to generate new migration file for adding the relation.

Comment: Thank you @Sohel0415 and @ DharmaSuptra - I'll create a new migration. where may I add the relations though? Is there a Notify model that I can edit?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra I updated my post so it is more clear. Thanks much if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually to define which field to show/save, and then you need it to display, you only need to modify the `toDatabase` method. Example:

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();

    return [
        'requester_id' => $user->id,
        'requester_name' => $user->name,
        // and more data that you need to show
    ];
}
```

So for relational data or any other data, just define it inside this method. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks @Dharma, however this is hard coded into data json. If hte user changes their name for instance I wont get that updated. Do you have any ideas no how to get a relation live, like with other models?

Comment: Maybe you could try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646085/laravel-5-4-5-3-customize-or-extend-notifications-database-model#answer-43658694. It's creating new Notification Channel, but basicly its extended from DatabaseChannel.