# Use whereHas along with Carbon in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose there is a `Website` model like this :

```
class Website extends Authenticatable
{
        protected $primaryKey = 'website_id';

        public function deposits ()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(\App\AdminDeposit::class, 'website', 'website_id');
        }

}
```

And in the other hand there is a `AdminDepoist` Model like this:

```
class AdminDeposit extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'deposit_id';

        public function website ()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(\App\Website::class, 'website', 'website_id');
        }

    }
```

As you can see there is one to many relationship between them where each website can have some deposits.

`AdminDeposit` model has a `created_at` attribute that setted each time a new deposit inserted.

Now I want to select websites that is left less than **5** days from last their deposits. (means `if(website->last_deposit <= 5 days)`)

then I want to select websites that their last deposit between **5** and **10** days.

and finally those that their last deposit is greater than **30** days.

I know that should be used `whereHas()` along with **Carbon** library but I do not know how?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `hasOne` relationship to [get one latest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48057156/1227923) deposit:

```
public function latestDeposit()
{
    return $this->hasOne(AdminDeposit::class, 'website', 'website_id')->latest();
}
```

> Websites that is left less than 5 days from last their deposit

```
Website::whereHas('latestDeposit', function($q) {
    $q->where('created_at', '>', now()->subDays(5));
})->get();
```

> Websites that their last deposit between 5 and 10 days.

```
Website::whereHas('latestDeposit', function($q) {
    $q->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subDays(10), now()->subDays(5)]);
})->get();
```

> Those that their last deposit is greater than 30 days

```
Website::whereHas('latestDeposit', function($q) {
    $q->where('created_at', '<', now()->subDays(30));
})->get();
```