# Laravel - get last row using whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the time "created_at" for the last user activity,
I have the model `User`, and `UserActivity`.
I want to get the last user activity and check if the last activity of this user is 3 days to send notification,

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{
    public function activites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Activty::class);
    }

}
```

**Activity.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Activity extends Model
{
    function function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$latest_activites = User::whereHas("activites",function($query){
            $query->where("created_at",">=",Carbon::now()->subDays(3));
        });
$latest_activites = $latest_activites->get();
```

Comment: You you want to check this only for one user (current user)?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin no for all, I want to send reminder message for all users with the last activity is 3 days

Comment: If you want to get all users with last activity 3 days ago or more, please check my answer.

Comment: but I want to get the last activity only, I want to get the activity information, not just the users, anyway to do it ?

Comment: But to send a notification you still need a user instance. So, you need to get a user with just one latest notification? Also, the relationship is `hasMany()`?

Comment: yes, the user have many activities, i want to check the last activity of the user only, not all of them, if I have old one and new one it will show the old one aslo

Comment: So, you need to get the latest activity for one user. Please check updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create another relationship in `User` model, which [has to be `hasOne` to get the latest activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48057156/1227923):

```
public function latestActivity()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Activity::class)->latest();
}
```

Then load just users who have latest activities older than 3 days

```
$users = User::whereHas('activites', function($q) {
        $q->where('created_at', '<=', now()->subDays(3));
    })
    ->whereDoesntHave('activites', function($q) {
        $q->where('created_at', '>', now()->subDays(3));
    })
    ->with('latestActivity')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've incidentally added another answer instead of editing the old one. This query will get only users who have activities older than 3 days and doesn't have new ones. It will also load the latest activity for each user (just one per user).

Comment: Thank you, I guess this will work, I will try it now, is it better to loop though the activities instead of users or not ?

Comment: @Peril you can iterate over users and get the latest activity with `$user->latestActivity` without any additional DB queries.

Comment: Thank you alexey, I still have problem, I get the users twice, I tried to make groupBy but it didnt work

Comment: @Peril you can't get users twice with my code. Just copy paste it and do not use `groupBy`. Does it work if you do not modify it?

Answer (score 4):

You should eagerload user activities at the same time then with subquery filter based on created_at. Call the latest to get last record and you should be good to go.

```
$latest_activites = User::with('activites')
                         ->where("activites",function($query){

             $query->where("created_at",">=",Carbon::now()->subDays(3));

        })->latest()->get();
```

Comment: On your first where clause if there is not column named `activities` on your database, then you will getting an error. Instead, you need to use `whereHas()` instead of using the `where`.

Answer (score 1):

main structure: `model::latest()->get()`

```
  $latest_activites = User::with('activites')
                    ->where("activites",function($query){
                     .
                     .
                     .
                     .
            })->latest()->get();
```