# How to get latest activity record in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

How to get latest updated or created record in laravel

if i use latest() it only considered created_by value.

```
$tasks->latest();
```

if i use orderBy

```
$tasks->orderBy('created_at,'DESC');
```

then it is not working for latest updated.

```
$tasks->orderBy('updated_at,'DESC');
```

then its is not working for created_at

How to get latest created or latest updated Record. Basically, the most recent activity record?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - get last row using whereHas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276324/laravel-get-last-row-using-wherehas)

Comment: just order by `updated_at` field, this will fetch the most recent activity record

Comment: `$tasks->latest('your_column');`.. also you can use multiple orderBy in chain..`$tasks->orderBy('created_at,'DESC')->orderBy('updated_at,'DESC');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$tasks->orderBy('updated_at,'DESC');
```

`updated_at` is the most recent timestamp on any activity (created/updated), so this should work in both the cases.