# Laravel Eloquent Join but only show max row from relationship

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I have two Models **Customer**, **Contact** with the following relation:

```
// Customer Model
public function contacts() {
    return $this->hasMany('Contact', 'customer_id')    
}
```

Contacts look like this:

```
id | created_at | body | customer_id
1  | 2018-01-03 | text | 1
2  | 2018-01-01 | text | 2
3  | 2017-12-25 | text | 1
4  | 2017-10-13 | text | 2
5  | 2017-10-03 | text | 2
```

Now I want to create a view with a list of all my customers including the latest contact per customer with only **one row per customer**. It shall look something like this:

```
Customer ID | Name | Last Contact Date
1           | John | 2018-01-03
2           | Max  | 2018-01-01
...         | ...  | ...
```

I already tried to achieve this with something like

```
// Customer Model
public function contactsList () {
    return $this->contacts()
                ->leftJoin('contacts', 'customers.id', '=', 'contacts.customer_id')
                ->groupBy('customer.id')
                ->orderByRaw('contacts.created_at desc');
}
```

but it's not what I expected. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work you need to [create a new `hasOne()` relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48057156/1227923) in `Customer` model:

```
public function latestContact()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Contact::class)->latest();
}
```

Then use it:

```
$customersWithLatestContact = Customer::with('latestContact')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a lot easier than expected. One more thing: How can handle customers that do not have a contact yet? For those I receive the following errror: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: @maxiw46 use the `optional()` helper when you're displaying the data `optional($customer->latestContact)->address` or just check it manually with `@if (!empty($customer->latestContact))`

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much!