# Laravel: Model function to check if relationship exists

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models **Customer**, **Contact** with the following relationship in the Customer model:

```
public function latestContact () {
    return $this->hasOne(Contact::class)->latest();
}
```

I already found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822299/laravel-eloquent-join-but-only-show-max-row-from-relationship) that the optional helper is a possible to way check if the relationship exists when displaying the data. Otherwise I would receive a *"Trying to get property of non-object"* error.

```
optional($customer->latestContact)->address
```

Now I am wondering if there is a way to directly check this inside the model function. I would prefer to only call

```
$customer->latestContact->address
```

or something like

```
$customer->getLatestContactAdress
```

and return false (or no result) if the relationship does not exists.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910553/laravel-check-if-related-model-existsfollow above url

Comment: If your relationship is hasOne why you want to call latest()

Comment: @afsalc The actual relationsship is hasMany(). With the latestContact function, I call only the latest Contact for a Customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [define an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) or a function within your parent model.

Something like this in your Customer model:

```
public function getLatestContactAddress()
{
    return optional($this->latestContact)->address;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
$customer->getLatestContactAddress();
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is what I've been looking for. I'll try it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Try using eager loading

```
$customer = Customer::with('latestContact')->get();
```

Let me know if not works